# No error when running unit test with an expectation on method calls (Ruby/Test::Unit/Mocha)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking

I have a question regaring Mocha expectations running with the Ruby Test::Unit framework.
My purpose is to verify the methods called when I call a wrapping method.
This test always seem to pass, I don't understand why...
I am expecting an error stating that the method clean has only be called once (with can be verified in the Expectation object). 
Why is the following Unit Test not raising an error when I run the following test:

```rb
    require 'test/unit'
    require 'mocha'
    require 'mocha/test_unit'

    class DoMe
      def stop_and_clean
      clean
      stop
    end

    def clean
      true
    end

    def stop
      true
    end
  end

    class DoMeTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
      def test_stop_and_clean
      d = DoMe.new
      d.expects(:clean).times(5)

      assert(d.stop_and_clean)
    end  
   end
```

It seems to me that expects(:clean).times(5) will not be satisfied, but running the test shows no error. Do I need to make an assertion on the Expectation object ?

```
exp = d.expects(:clean).times(5)
[...]
assert(that exp is invoked only once)
```

Comment: It shouldn't show an error, it should show a failure.  I'm able to run the same code and get a failed expectation: `expected exactly 5 times, invoked once: #<DoMe:0x7f89fa8c7b80>.clean(any_parameters)`